# What is the space complexity for this function?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, big-o

I am trying to learn the concept of space time complexity. I have a simple function here that will compare two arrays, and check if the second one has corresponding squared values to the first. I understand the time complexity more and believe it would be `O(n)` for this example. However, for space I am confused if it would be `O(1)` since we are always setting a boolean variable (works) and a i inside the loop, or do we have to take in account for the inputs that can be of different sizes? Thanks

```
let checkSquared = (arr, arr2) => {
    let works = true;
    works = arr.length === arr2.length

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        works = arr2[i] === (arr[i] * arr[i])
    }

    return works;
}
```

Comment: You iterate through the array, therefore it's `O(n)`

Comment: The *memory usage* of your code seems to be constant regardless of the size of the input. Hence I would assume it's `O(1)`

Comment: @VLAZ for time that makes sense, but we aren't creating new variables in the loop so why would be space be o(n)?

Comment: On a separate note `arr.length !== arr2.length && (works = false)` either write the `if` statement or do `works = arr.length !== arr2.length` - there is no need to do a single line conditional without putting the conditional code there. Same with the line inside the `for` loop - just make it `works = arr2[i] !== (arr[i] * arr[i])`

Comment: @haim770 ok so when calculating space, do you only look at the memory usage inside the function and not treat the inputs as variables?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought you meant TIME complexity. Yes, the space complexity is `O(1)`, you aren't taking up more memory in a linear manner or anything. It's always the same variables, regardless of input.

Comment: @VLAZ that code inside the () after the && is the condition code. It is basically a ternary but with only a if statement.

Comment: @matt, It's the space used by *your code* that we're interested in. If it gets pointers to huge data-structures as arguments, that's not your code that is allocating that space.

Comment: @matt I know what the code does. It's not needed - you've made it needlessly more complex to read. Just make the comparisong as an assignment `a == b && c = true` is the same as `c = a == b`. The latter is shorter and clearer because we know you're making an assignment from the start, we don't need to read the *end* of the line to find out that, and then go back to the beginning to figure out *when*.

Comment: @VLAZ ahhh I see what you are saying, yes it would be better to just say works =  arr2[i] === (arr[i] * arr[i]

Comment: @vlaz no, `works = (...)` won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gets passed two arrays, by reference, so it's just two references to already existing objects. Inside, it creates a boolean `works`, a number `i`, and possibly allocates some temporary space for intermediary values.

All in all, O(1).

Comment: ok thanks, now just for example if instead inside the loop we were reassigning works to be a string each time that varied with the input.. that would be o(n) because the string can be different sizes correct?

Comment: It depends what would be in that string. Usually, it would probably be O(m, n) (where m=arr.length and n=arr2.length).